# transforming a plist in another nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsarray, plist

I'm not english, new to objective c and new to this website. But i hope you will understand my problem. I tried to use the search engine but i couldn't find a answer...

THE PROBLEM:
i have a plist file like this

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>001</string>
    <key>CAT</key>
    <string>A</string>
    <key>TITLE</key>
    <string>AAAA01</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>002</string>
    <key>CAT</key>
    <string>A</string>
    <key>TITLE</key>
    <string>AAAA02</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>003</string>
    <key>CAT</key>
    <string>B</string>
    <key>TITLE</key>
    <string>BBBB01</string>
</dict>
.....
</array>
</plist>
```

so i have many entries like this. every entry has a category (CAT) like in my example "A" and "B".
now i need a code to transform this to the following:

```
NSArray
    NSDictionary
        CAT => "A"
        VALUES => {"AAAA01","AAAA02"}
    NSDictionary
        CAT => "B"
        VALUES => {"BBBB01", ...}
    ETC.
```

MY SOLUTION:

i get the plist with the following code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Dictonary" ofType:@"plist"];
arrayIndex = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now i have everything saved in the arrayIndex but then i dont find a way to transform the code in a new array to get my wanted result.

please can anybody help me?

THANK YOU very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight programming.

It is more easily done in two steps saving trying to find an entry to add to.

```
// First create a dictionary of CAT and the values,
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSDictionary *item in arrayIndex) {
        NSString *cat = [item valueForKey:@"CAT"];

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [tempDict valueForKey:cat];
        if (!tempArray) {
            tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [tempDict setValue:tempArray forKey:cat];
        }

        NSString *v = [item valueForKey:@"TITLE"];
        [tempArray addObject:v];
    }
    NSLog(@"tempDict: %@", tempDict);
// This may well be a good final result


// This step transforms the dictionary into a list of dictionaries    
    NSMutableArray *newList = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *keys = [[tempDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    for (NSString *cat in keys) {
        [newList addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            cat, @"CAT",
                            [tempDict valueForKey:cat], @"VALUES",
                            nil]];
    }
    NSLog(@"newList: %@", newList);
```

Comment: thank you very much for spending your time. its working great.

Comment: hm i have another problem now, i use your code inside a table view. there is no compiler error, but after running it the app crashes at the moment I start scrolling in my table view.are there memory leaks?
any ideas?

Comment: Best advice, open another question and post some code. Also, accepting answers gives you reputation points as well as the person who answers.